# Can't move Webapp to new resource group

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I successfully moved several resources via REST API into other resource groups (using [this howto](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2015/05/27/moving-resources-with-arm/)) but it failed when I tried to move a WebApp and its service plan. I know there are [limitations](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-move-resources/): I have to move the entire resource group and the target resource group mustn't contain a WebApp. So my target resource group is empty and my source resource group only contains the WebApp and the service plan.
As suggested in the howto, I wrote this JSON:

```
{
  "targetResourceGroup": "/subscriptions/Subscription-B/resourceGroups/newRG",
  "resources": [
    "/subscriptions/Subscription-A/resourceGroups/oldRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/test",
    "/subscriptions/Subscription-A/resourceGroups/oldRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/test"
  ]
}
```

and run it via command:

```
armclient post https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/Subscription-A/resourceGroups/oldRG/moveResources?api-version=2015-01-01 @path/to/my/json -verbose
```

I get "202: accepted" in the command window and in the portal I see in both resource groups (oldRG and newRG) the info text "resources being moved" but after a minute, nothing has changed.

Edit:
When I click on "delete" in the oldRG, I see all the contained ressources: there are 4 alertrules, 1 autoscalesetting and 1 certificate.
As mentioned in the limitations, I have to move *all* of them. But how can I access these 3 types of ressources? I don't have their ressource ID because I don't find them when I search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate resource Id looks like:

```
/subscriptions/Subscription-A/resourceGroups/oldRG/providers/Microsoft.Web/certificates/<certificateThumbprint>
```

You don't have to pass in autoscale settings or alert rules.

Comment: Thank you for this information! But sadly it does not work at all. For testing I also created a new resource group with a new WebApp/ServicePlan and a new empty resource group. It also fails when I try to move the new WebApp in the empty resource group =/

Comment: I tried to include the autoscale and alert rules: The movement is now busy for 1 hour...

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a combination of Zain Rizvi's answer and this:
I thought it does not matter, that's why I told you the names of the both resource groups are `oldRG` and `newRG` - but actually **they have the same name**. That was the problem. Even if they are in different subscriptions, I wasn't able to move my resources into a resource-group with the same name as the current resource has. So I created a new empty resourcegroup (*tmpRG*) inside subscriptionB and moved my resources from *subscriptionA\myRG* to *subscriptionB\tmpRG* and then from *subscriptionB\tmpRG* to *subscriptionB\myRG*.